# I'm getting an error while trying to read drawable file name.png using InputStream. Why?

Tags: android, file-io, inputstream, drawable

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.name);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(data);
os.write(data);
```

The R.drawble is getting an error of "Content mismatch"

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your resource to `res/raw/`, then use `openRawResource()` as you have it, for `R.raw.name`.

Or, move your resource to `assets/`, then use `open()` on an `AssetManager` to get your `InputStream`.